# How can I properly integrate the add and mul methods in my class?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've got a lesson doubt. Here is the objective from the class exercise:

> Objective: Define a Python class V2, which represents two-dimensional vectors and supports the following operations:
>
> - Create a new vector out of two real numbers: v = V2(1.1, 2.2)
> - Convert a vector to a string (with the `__str__` method)
> - Access the components (with the getX and getY methods)
> - Add two V2s to get a new V2 (with add and `__add__` methods)
> - Multiply a V2 by a scalar (real or int) and return a new V2 (with the mul
>     and `__mul__` methods)
>
> Further information is given here:
>
> Step 3. Define the add and mul methods, so that you get the following behavior:
>
> ```
> >>> a = V2(1.0, 2.0) 
> >>> b = V2(2.2, 3.3)
> >>> print a.add(b)
> V2[3.2, 5.3]
> >>> print a.mul(2)
> V2[2.0, 4.0]
> >>> print a.add(b).mul(-1)
> V2[-3.2, -5.3]
> ```

Here is what I've been able to code:

```
class V2:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.vector = [x, y]
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return 'V2[' + str(self.x) + ', ' + str(self.y) + ']'
    def __add__(self, other):
        return 'V2[' + str(self.x + other.x) + ', ' + str(self.y + other.y) + ']'
    def add(self, other):
        return 'V2[' + str(self.x + other.x) + ', ' + str(self.y + other.y) + ']'
    def __mul__(self, y):
        return 'V2[' + str(self.x * y) + ', ' + str(self.y * y) + ']'
    def mul(self, y):
        return 'V2[' + str(self.x * y) + ', ' + str(self.y * y) + ']'
    def getX(self):
        return self.x
    def getY(self):
        return self.y
```

My question is how can I get `print a.add(b)mul(-1)` right? When I try to run this:

```
>>> p1 = V2(3, 2)
>>> p2 = V2(2, 3)
>>> p1.add(p2).mul(-1)
```

This error shows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    p1.add(p2).mul(-1)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mul'
```

I think I understand the error but I can't come up with a different way to do the `add` and `mul` methods without messing up other methods.

Comment: Why are you returning strings from your `add` method, anyway?

Answer (score 2):

You need to create another instance of your class instead of a string:

```
def __add__(self, v):
    return self.__class__(self.x + v.x, self.y + v.y)

def __mul__(self, n):
    return self.__class__(self.x * n, self.y * n)
```

You can then use `def add(self, v): return self + v`.  You might switch those, so that `add()` is the main method, and `__add__` calls `add`.

Comment: You're so goddamn right. Could you explain how you used the __class__ method. It's the first time I've seen it.

Comment: `__class__` is an attribute of the instance that store the class that the instance is of.  Using that instead of `V2` guarantees that subclasses will return instances of the subclass instead of necessarily being instances of `V2` directly.

Comment: Would I have to create the __class__ method. If yes, how would I do this?

Comment: Nope.  That attribute is built-in to every instance.

Comment: This really helped wrap my head around. Ty

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that in each of your methods you are returning a string. You can't do any arithmetic with a string.Currently, your add method returns a string which then you call mul on (e.g. "[v1 3 4]".mul).

Change your add and mult method to the following where you return a V2.

```
 def __add__(self, other):
        return V2(self.x + other.x,self.y * other.y)
 def __mul__(self, ascalar):
        return V2(self.x * ascalar, self.y * ascalar)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your methods, you are returning strings, instead of new instances of V2. So it should be:

```
class V2:
def __init__(self, x, y):
    self.vector = [x, y]
    self.x = x
    self.y = y
def __str__(self):
    return 'V2[' + str(self.x) + ', ' + str(self.y) + ']'
def __add__(self, other):
    return V2(self.x + other.x, self.y + other.y)
def __mul__(self, c):
    return V2(self.x * c ,self.y * c)
def getX(self):
    return self.x
def getY(self):
    return self.y
```